# Extracting the body of a function

Tags: manipulate

I have a very simple issue with Mathematica, but I can't seem to find an answer for it.

I solved an equation with DSolve, and I got a result as an array of the following type:

```
Solution = { A11 -> Function[ {t} , expression1] , A22 ->Function[ {t}, expression 2] , etc }
```

Now I want to define a matrix with elements `{{A11, A12},{A21, A22}}` and to give these elements the values for expression1, expression 2, etc, essentially to put those functions in a matrix:

```
{{ expression 1, expression 2},{ expression 3, expression 4}}
```

What I tried so far is to use

```
R11 = {A11} /. Solution[[1]]
```

, but it gives R11 the value `Function [ {t} , expression 1]` and not `expression 1`.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `g = Function[{t}, expression1 t]; Module[{t}, g[[2]]]`

Comment: This just gives Function[{t},expression 1]. I want to extract expression 1 out of there.

Comment: No, it returns `expression1 t`, at least in Mathematica v9.

Answer (score 3):

There are two syntaxes for `DSolve`:

```
In[5]:= DSolve[x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x, t]
Out[5]= {{x -> Function[{t}, C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]]}}

In[6]:= DSolve[x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[t], t]
Out[6]= {{x[t] -> C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]}}
```

Notice that one returns the solution for `x`, the other for `x[t]`.  Both are meant to be substituted into `x[t]`, and will give the same result after the substitution:

```
In[7]:= x[t] /. %5
Out[7]= {C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]}

In[8]:= x[t] /. %6
Out[8]= {C[1] Cos[t] + C[2] Sin[t]}
```

So the key is to use `{{A11[t], A12[t]},{A21[t], A22[t]}}` instead of `{{A11, A12},{A21, A22}}`.

Generally, the "extract the expression in a `Function`" just means *applying* the function:  `Function[x, x^2][t]` gives `t^2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MMA 10 try `DSolveValue` instead of `DSolve`. In this case may help this:

```
(*extracting expressions from Function*)
t = Solution /. func_Function :> func[[2]];
(*extracting expressions from Rule*)
t /. rule_Rule -> rule[[2]]
```

Comment: WORKS: The way to solve the problem is the following `element = Res /. func_Function :> func[[2]]` and then combine it with `RhoSol = {{\[Rho]11 /. element[[1]], \[Rho]12 /. 
     element[[2]]}, {\[Rho]21 /. element[[3]], \[Rho]22 /. 
     element[[4]]}};`  Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (make a matrix of elements Aij[t] and substitute the functions you have found):

```
sol = {A11 -> Function[{t}, expression1], A12 -> Function[{t}, expression2],
  A21 -> Function[{t}, expression3], A22 -> Function[{t}, expression4]};

Partition[Through[{A11, A12, A21, A22} [t]], 2] /. sol
```

(* {{expression1, expression2}, {expression3, expression4}} *)

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[t];
{#[[0]], #[[1]], #[[2]]} &@Function[{t}, expression1 t] //Column

(*
Function
{t}
expression1 t

*)
```